# (parameter) children: ReactNode Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-typescript

1-(parameter) children: ReactNode
Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.

2-Property 'type' does not exist on type 'boolean | ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.
Property 'type' does not exist on type 'string'.

```
import Head from "next/head"

interface AppProps{
  children: React.ReactNode
}
const Layout = ({ children }: AppProps) => {
  return (
    <>
       <Head>
       <title>{children.type.name}</title>
       </Head>
   </>
  )
}
export default Layout
```

Answer (score 0):

The type `ReactNode` is the union type `boolean | React.ReactChild | React.ReactFragment | React.ReactPortal | null | undefined`. As you can see, that includes `null` and `undefined`, so you have to handle the possibility that `children` will be `null` or `undefined` in your code.

**How** you handle it is up to you. You could not render anything in `Layout`, or throw an error, or render some placeholder text instead of `children.type.name`.